# Mac でフォルダの保存をしようとするとアクセス権がありませんと保存できません

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

タイトル通りmacでrailsのフォルダhtml.erbを保存しようとするとファイルにアクセス権がありませんとでて保存できないです。
対処法として上タブの情報を見るの共有とアクセス権で自分の方を読み/書きできるように設定したりしましたがそれでも解決できないままです。

どなたかMacを使っている方で私と似たような事になったことのある方がいましたらご教授頂けると幸いです。
エラー画像は以下のようなものが出て対処法はMacのページから試しました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 画像が小さすぎて文字が読み取れません。デスクトップ全体ではなく必要な範囲をキャプチャするか、どのフォルダに保存しようとしているのかを「文字の情報」で追記してみてください。

Comment: このエディタは Mac の「テキストエディット」ですか？　また、保存しようとしているファイルの置き場所（パス）はどこでしょうか。

Comment: 保存先はデスクトップでテキストエディットであってあります。